# SVG doesn't show ok in IE

Tags: svg

I have an `svg` file. If I open it in Chrome it looks ok (you can see the lighthouse in the middle), but opening in IE (no matter which version), it doesn't show image the right way. Any idea what it could be? You can download file and image here:

[svgfilelink](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByTr5TBi-A13SWNDZFpiMUZJY1U/view)

This is the code:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 189.92 311.81" style="enable-background:new 0 0 189.92 311.81;" xml:space="preserve" width="400" height="400">
<g id="bg">
        <rect x="-5.67" y="-5.67" class="editable" color-values="#9B2632;#64FE2E;#0000FF" data-type="color-picker" data-label="Background" style="fill:#9B2632;" width="201.26" height="323.15"></rect>
</g>
<g id="white_line">
        <rect x="5.67" y="5.67" style="fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-miterlimit:10;" width="178.58" height="283.46"></rect>
</g>
<g id="pattern">
        <g style="opacity:0.2;">
        <path style="opacity:0.7;fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M26.36,289.13h11.85c-1.03-0.39-2.15-0.73-3.42-1
            C31.37,287.51,28.35,288.23,26.36,289.13z"></path>
        <path style="opacity:0.7;fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M81.16,284.63c-4.8-1.44-6.91,2.77-6.91,2.77c-3.24-5.08-9.99-3.47-10.62,1.72
            c0,0,0,0,0,0H84.6C84.47,287.38,83.71,285.4,81.16,284.63z"></path>
        <path style="opacity:0.7;fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M153.89,283.25c0.03-0.84-0.12-1.82-0.4-2.86c-0.21-0.76-0.61-1.89-1.19-3.17
            c0.33,0,0.66-0.02,0.98-0.04c-0.42-0.14-0.81-0.31-1.22-0.46c-0.17-0.36-0.35-0.72-0.55-1.09c-2.46-4.77-6.97-8.06-11.99-9.35
            c-3.11-5.05-4.48-11.18-3.46-17.41c2.65-12.99,16.48-22.18,29.4-16.56c8.23,3.13,12.79,11.53,11.43,20.39
            c-1.27,4.13-3.73,8.22-7.34,10.52c10.19-5.12,9.91-19.95,2.36-27.22c-9.87-9.69-25.35-6.47-33.27,3.44
            c6.77-11.72,23.42-14.32,33.91-5.8c8.14,7.29,10.25,19.78,2.96,28.51c-6.7,8.15-19.17,9.68-26.72,1.8
            c-7.55-7.27-5.49-20.27,4.08-24.81c6.55-2.56,15.44,1.35,16.79,8.82c-0.25-0.18-0.55-0.34-0.91-0.45c-2.76-0.83-3.98,1.6-3.98,1.6
            c-1.87-2.92-5.75-2-6.11,0.99c-0.36,2.99,3.21,5.73,6.05,7.46c4.36-2.58,5.66-5.42,5.8-5.66c0.11-0.2,0.72-2.47-0.6-3.73
            c-0.29-4.24-3.38-7.26-6.94-9.4c-5.28-2.48-11.26-0.24-15.49,3.83c-3.63,4.07-4.35,9.39-3.27,14.74
            c3.29,12.52,19.81,15.84,29.29,8c0.87-0.81,1.7-1.69,2.46-2.64c9.27-11,3.72-28.9-9.81-33.93c-9.41-3.16-19.55-0.41-26.22,6.56
            c-6.09,7.57-8.08,17.6-4.8,26.81c0.07,1.2,0.29,2.4,0.64,3.57c-4.03-0.22-8.13,0.86-11.56,3.49c-4.14,3.31-8.14,10.84-3.16,14.71
            c2.61-4.53,5.2-10.11,11.31-10.93c4.86-0.36,9.16,1.63,12.02,5.57c2.07,3.39,2.56,7.14,1.8,10.62h6.76
            c0.27-0.81,0.5-1.65,0.67-2.5C153.93,284.96,153.96,283.72,153.89,283.25z"></path>
        <path style="opacity:0.7;fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M15.9,229.46c-1.68,2.14-6.49,3.76-6.49,3.76s5.75,1.48,8.97,1.98
            c-0.88,0.85-1.69,2.06-2.78,4.08c-1.24,2.28-1.69,6.59-1.85,9.26c-0.21,3.34-3.95,8.33-3.95,8.33s9.65-3.51,12.08-5.1
            c1.89-1.25,3.04-2.15,3.86-3.83c0.34,1.68,0.8,3.3,1.38,4.84c2.07,6.17,5.75,10.92,9.85,14.29c2.05,1.69,4.21,3.1,6.31,4.07
            c2.11,1.09,4.15,2.3,6.01,2.13c3.76,1.43,6.88,1.35,9.19,0.86c2.11,0.25,3.53-0.4,3.79-0.47c4.44-0.83,6.99-3.91,6.12-5.53
            c-0.9-1.73-4.07-1.82-7.38-1.23c-0.38,0.02-4.11,1.13-10.14-0.18c-1.34-0.28-2.82-0.75-4.33-1.42c0.2,0.06,0.4,0.13,0.6,0.18
            c3.52,0.89,7.65,0.77,11.04-0.33c3.42-1.03,5.91-2.79,7.06-3.77c3.25-2.87,3.33-7.22,2-9.1c-1.28-2.03-3.01-2.07-3.73-1.35
            c-0.79,0.74-0.98,1.99-1.5,2.94c-0.47,1-1.11,1.59-1.66,2.09c-1.33,1.27-5.29,4.91-10.86,5.58c-2.69,0.35-5.52,0-7.79-0.79
            c-1.66-0.57-2.99-1.36-3.96-2.01c-1.88-2.2-3.52-4.87-4.66-8.08c-3.79-9.72-2.26-23.76,7.2-33.24c2.33-2.39,5.12-4.41,8.2-6.02
            c-2.68,2.95-4.05,6.73-4.12,10.09c0.02,4.49,1.19,8.06,3.91,10.37c2.7,1.94,4.92,1.51,5.09,1.57c1.94-0.16,2.79-1.85,2.14-2.82
            c-0.66-1.04-1.71-1.57-2.41-1.54c-0.07-0.04-1.02,0.19-2.24-0.63c-0.97-0.57-2.52-3.64-2.46-6.87c-0.04-3.3,1.6-7.27,5.06-9.7
            c3.69-2.27,8.47-4.07,13.26-4.64c0.89-0.12,1.78-0.18,2.67-0.21c3.16,0.18,6.3,0.72,9.32,1.67c-0.1-0.02-0.19-0.04-0.29-0.05
            c-4.98-0.83-10.41-0.04-13.88,1.23c-1.16,0.43-2.01,1.07-2.82,1.54c-3.15,1.8-6.23,5.05-3.69,8.22c1.95,2.42,4.52,1.41,6.47-0.2
            c0.36-0.29,0.58-0.43,0.82-0.66c0,0,0.35-0.3,0.37-0.32c0,0,0.27-0.23,0.56-0.47c0.82-0.62,1.08-0.86,1.73-1.35
            c0.66-0.49,1.32-0.91,2.07-1.25c0.62-0.31,1.3-0.63,2.03-0.94c1.45-0.61,3.09-1.16,4.8-1.52c2.25-0.52,4.58-0.71,6.65-0.54
            c-3.43,0.24-6.87,1.51-8.99,2.85c-0.75,0.46-1.24,1.04-1.74,1.48c-1.93,1.71-3.6,4.42-1.36,6.25c1.71,1.4,3.34,0.32,4.46-1.07
            c0.2-0.27,0.33-0.39,0.47-0.59c0,0,0.2-0.27,0.21-0.28c0,0,0.16-0.19,0.33-0.41c0.47-0.55,0.62-0.75,1-1.19
            c0.38-0.44,0.78-0.84,1.25-1.18c0.39-0.32,0.81-0.63,1.27-0.95c0.93-0.64,1.98-1.26,3.11-1.76c1.68-0.78,3.5-1.3,5.1-1.41
            c0.54-0.05,1.05-0.04,1.53-0.01c0.54,0.38,1.08,0.76,1.61,1.16c-0.68-0.08-1.4-0.12-2.14-0.07c-2.69,0.11-5.44,1.12-7.1,2.16
            c-0.56,0.35-0.93,0.78-1.31,1.12c-1.44,1.28-2.69,3.31-1.01,4.69c1.28,1.05,2.5,0.24,3.35-0.81c0.15-0.2,0.25-0.29,0.36-0.44
            c0,0,0.15-0.19,0.16-0.2c0,0,0.11-0.15,0.23-0.31c0.35-0.41,0.47-0.57,0.75-0.89c0.29-0.33,0.59-0.63,0.94-0.88
            c0.28-0.24,0.61-0.47,0.95-0.71c0.69-0.48,1.48-0.95,2.33-1.33c1.27-0.58,2.63-0.97,3.83-1.06c0.08-0.01,0.16,0,0.24,0
            c0.17,0.14,0.33,0.3,0.5,0.44c-1.06,0.27-2.02,0.69-2.71,1.12c-0.37,0.23-0.61,0.51-0.85,0.72c-0.94,0.84-1.76,2.17-0.67,3.07
            c0.84,0.68,1.64,0.15,2.19-0.53c0.1-0.13,0.17-0.19,0.23-0.29c0,0,0.09-0.13,0.1-0.14c0,0,0.09-0.09,0.16-0.19
            c0.24-0.28,0.31-0.38,0.5-0.59c0.19-0.21,0.39-0.4,0.61-0.57c0.19-0.15,0.4-0.31,0.63-0.46c0.39-0.27,0.85-0.54,1.33-0.76
            c5.68,5.47,9.8,12.47,11.76,19.86c4,13.19,2.09,26.66-2.39,36.7c-1.35,2.95-2.85,5.56-4.41,7.92c0.21-0.48,0.43-0.97,0.62-1.47
            c1.98-5.37,2.46-11.78,1.29-17.06c-1.05-5.33-3.41-9.28-4.74-11.11c-3.96-5.17-10.76-5.54-13.9-3.6
            c-3.41,1.88-3.74,4.54-2.74,5.69c1.03,1.27,2.96,1.62,4.36,2.48c1.49,0.79,2.31,1.8,2.99,2.67c1.78,2.12,6.81,8.44,6.96,17.08
            c0.1,4.02-0.82,8.21-2.34,11.61h5.37c3.13-3.42,6.25-7.71,8.98-13.06c0.11-0.22,0.21-0.45,0.31-0.68
            c-0.18,0.98-0.33,2.04-0.4,3.21c-0.28,3.06,0.29,6.82,1.8,10.53h12.75c-1.99-0.89-5.01-1.61-8.43-1c-0.44,0.09-0.86,0.2-1.27,0.31
            c-0.49-1.07-0.92-2.16-1.27-3.27c-0.52-1.11-0.92-2.25-1.23-3.36c-0.3-1.11-0.49-2.21-0.55-3.26c-0.33-3.04-0.02-5.57,0.37-7.39
            c2.58-7,3.98-15.22,3.33-23.81c0.23-0.27,0.46-0.53,0.7-0.75c0.2-0.19,0.39-0.37,0.58-0.52c0.21-0.19,0.44-0.35,0.68-0.49
            c0.25-0.14,0.36-0.19,0.67-0.36c0.12-0.06,0.23-0.11,0.23-0.11c0.01-0.01,0.15-0.08,0.15-0.08c0.11-0.04,0.19-0.09,0.32-0.17
            c0.79-0.4,1.46-1.08,0.96-2.04c-0.66-1.25-2.12-0.72-3.14,0.04c-0.26,0.19-0.59,0.37-0.88,0.69c-0.2,0.21-0.4,0.46-0.61,0.73
            c-0.07-0.52-0.13-1.03-0.22-1.55c0.22-0.37,0.46-0.74,0.71-1.09c0.54-0.76,1.16-1.44,1.76-2.03c0.3-0.28,0.6-0.55,0.89-0.79
            c0.32-0.29,0.67-0.53,1.05-0.74c0.38-0.22,0.55-0.29,1.03-0.56c0.17-0.09,0.34-0.18,0.34-0.18c0.01,0,0.23-0.11,0.23-0.11
            c0.17-0.07,0.28-0.15,0.51-0.26c1.2-0.61,2.24-1.65,1.46-3.12c-1.01-1.92-3.25-1.1-4.8,0.05c-0.4,0.31-0.89,0.59-1.35,1.06
            c-0.89,0.94-1.87,2.35-2.61,3.95c-0.13-0.54-0.25-1.08-0.4-1.63c0.46-1.01,1.04-2.01,1.73-2.95c0.72-1.01,1.54-1.92,2.35-2.7
            c0.4-0.39,0.8-0.75,1.18-1.06c0.42-0.39,0.89-0.71,1.4-1c0.5-0.29,0.74-0.38,1.36-0.75c0.24-0.12,0.46-0.23,0.46-0.23
            c0.01-0.01,0.31-0.15,0.31-0.15c0.21-0.09,0.37-0.19,0.66-0.35c1.6-0.82,2.98-2.2,1.95-4.16c-1.35-2.56-4.34-1.46-6.41,0.08
            c-0.53,0.4-1.19,0.78-1.79,1.41c-1.64,1.72-3.46,4.6-4.43,7.72c-0.12-0.34-0.22-0.68-0.35-1.02c0.33-1.22,0.78-2.45,1.32-3.62
            c0.7-1.61,1.57-3.1,2.45-4.39c0.45-0.66,0.89-1.26,1.32-1.8c0.47-0.66,1.03-1.22,1.64-1.77c0.62-0.54,0.91-0.75,1.67-1.42
            c0.29-0.24,0.57-0.46,0.57-0.46c0.02-0.02,0.38-0.3,0.38-0.3c0.28-0.19,0.46-0.38,0.83-0.67c1.96-1.6,3.46-3.91,1.47-6.3
            c-2.6-3.13-6.39-0.76-8.79,1.97c-0.62,0.7-1.43,1.41-2.07,2.46c-1.53,2.47-2.99,6.19-3.63,10.11c-2.8-5.11-6.61-9.82-11.22-13.66
            c1.88-1.13,3.71-2.25,5.49-3.38l-0.04,0.44c0.27,1.11,1.35,3.71,2.14,5.56c0.92,2.17,3.65,1.84,4.36,0.73
            c1.26-1.96,1.62-2.8,1.5-6.41c-0.04-1.34-0.6-3.16-1.19-4.75c42.46-28.85,55.76-57.68,57.26-60.42c1.09-2,6.18-20.47-0.47-35.57
            c1.65,0.58,2.62,1.18,2.66,0.94c0.08-0.12-0.85-1.04-2.84-2.04c-0.13-0.07-0.28-0.13-0.42-0.2c-3.46-7.03-9.65-13.19-20.22-16.37
            c-0.04-0.01-0.08-0.02-0.12-0.03c1.08-0.42,2.19-1.04,3.33-1.62c2.1-0.97,4.26-2.38,6.31-4.07c4.1-3.38,7.79-8.12,9.85-14.29
            c0.57-1.54,1.03-3.16,1.37-4.84c0.82,1.68,1.97,2.58,3.86,3.83c2.42,1.59,12.08,5.1,12.08,5.1s-3.75-4.99-3.95-8.33
            c-0.17-2.67-0.62-6.98-1.85-9.26c-1.09-2.02-1.9-3.23-2.78-4.08c3.22-0.5,8.96-1.99,8.96-1.99s-4.81-1.62-6.49-3.76
            c-1.31-1.67-3.48-4.2-5.32-5.24c2.5-1.12,6.63-3.46,6.63-3.46s-4.22-0.27-6.04-1.63c-1.46-1.09-3.88-2.75-5.59-3.13
            c-3.19-0.69-4.01-0.44-5.98,0.58c-0.23,0.12-0.45,0.34-0.63,0.63c-1.03-1.33-2.15-2.62-3.4-3.83c-1.41-1.37-2.92-2.63-4.52-3.76
            c3.19-1.02,5.94-2.67,7.89-5.69c3.64-5.65,1.04-13.29-3.85-15.04c3.6,3.26,3.26,9.43-0.04,12.13c-3.4,2.86-6.47,3.88-11.18,3.63
            c-1.08,0.01-2.72-0.25-4.07-0.66c-0.16-0.04-0.31-0.06-0.47-0.1c-9.03-2.81-19.08-2.8-28.15,0.3
            c-11.33,3.54-20.43,11.92-25.82,21.74c-0.65-3.92-2.1-7.64-3.63-10.11c-0.65-1.05-1.45-1.76-2.07-2.46
            c-2.39-2.73-6.19-5.1-8.79-1.97c-1.99,2.4-0.48,4.71,1.47,6.3c0.37,0.29,0.55,0.47,0.83,0.67c0,0,0.36,0.28,0.38,0.3
            c0,0,0.28,0.22,0.57,0.46C73,37.79,73.3,38,73.91,38.54c0.61,0.55,1.17,1.11,1.64,1.77c0.43,0.54,0.88,1.15,1.32,1.8
            c0.88,1.3,1.75,2.79,2.45,4.4c0.54,1.18,0.98,2.41,1.32,3.62c-0.12,0.34-0.23,0.68-0.35,1.02c-0.97-3.11-2.79-5.99-4.43-7.72
            c-0.61-0.63-1.27-1.01-1.79-1.41c-2.07-1.54-5.06-2.64-6.41-0.08c-1.03,1.96,0.36,3.34,1.95,4.16c0.3,0.15,0.45,0.25,0.66,0.35
            c0,0,0.3,0.14,0.31,0.15c0,0,0.23,0.11,0.46,0.23c0.63,0.36,0.86,0.46,1.36,0.75c0.51,0.29,0.98,0.6,1.4,1
            c0.38,0.31,0.78,0.67,1.18,1.06c0.81,0.77,1.63,1.68,2.35,2.7c0.69,0.93,1.27,1.94,1.73,2.95c-0.15,0.54-0.27,1.08-0.4,1.63
            c-0.74-1.6-1.71-3.01-2.61-3.95c-0.46-0.47-0.95-0.75-1.35-1.06c-1.55-1.15-3.79-1.97-4.8-0.05c-0.78,1.47,0.26,2.5,1.46,3.12
            c0.22,0.11,0.33,0.19,0.51,0.26c0,0,0.22,0.11,0.23,0.11c0,0,0.17,0.09,0.34,0.18c0.48,0.27,0.65,0.34,1.03,0.56
            c0.38,0.21,0.73,0.46,1.05,0.74c0.29,0.24,0.58,0.51,0.89,0.79c0.6,0.58,1.22,1.27,1.76,2.03c0.26,0.35,0.49,0.72,0.71,1.09
            c-0.08,0.52-0.15,1.03-0.22,1.55c-0.2-0.27-0.41-0.52-0.61-0.73c-0.29-0.31-0.62-0.49-0.88-0.69c-1.02-0.76-2.47-1.29-3.14-0.04
            c-0.5,0.96,0.17,1.64,0.96,2.04c0.14,0.08,0.22,0.13,0.32,0.17c0,0,0.14,0.07,0.15,0.08c0,0,0.11,0.05,0.23,0.11
            c0.31,0.17,0.42,0.22,0.67,0.36c0.24,0.14,0.47,0.3,0.68,0.49c0.19,0.15,0.38,0.33,0.58,0.52c0.24,0.22,0.47,0.48,0.7,0.75
            c-0.66,8.59,0.74,16.82,3.33,23.81c0.35,1.63,0.63,3.83,0.45,6.45c-4.1-2.75-8.44-4.65-12.84-5.78c-0.79-1.03-1.67-1.95-2.57-2.66
            c-3.43-2.63-7.53-3.7-11.56-3.49c0.35-1.16,0.57-2.36,0.64-3.57c3.28-9.21,1.29-19.24-4.8-26.81c-6.67-6.98-16.8-9.72-26.22-6.56
            c-13.53,5.03-19.08,22.93-9.81,33.93c0.77,0.96,1.6,1.83,2.46,2.64c9.47,7.84,26,4.52,29.29-8c1.08-5.35,0.36-10.67-3.27-14.74
            c-4.24-4.07-10.21-6.31-15.49-3.83c-4.1,2.46-7.58,6.09-6.87,11.41c-0.19-8.89,9.79-13.84,16.96-11.03
            c9.58,4.54,11.63,17.54,4.08,24.81c-7.55,7.87-20.02,6.35-26.72-1.8C7.13,71.4,9.24,58.9,17.38,51.61
            c10.49-8.51,27.14-5.92,33.91,5.8c-7.92-9.91-23.4-13.13-33.27-3.44c-7.56,7.27-7.83,22.09,2.35,27.22
            c-3.61-2.3-6.07-6.39-7.34-10.52c-1.37-8.86,3.19-17.26,11.43-20.39c12.92-5.61,26.75,3.58,29.4,16.56
            c1.02,6.23-0.35,12.36-3.46,17.41c-5.02,1.29-9.54,4.59-11.99,9.35c-0.15,0.29-0.3,0.57-0.43,0.85c-0.24,0.15-0.48,0.31-0.71,0.47
            c-0.21,0.08-0.41,0.17-0.62,0.24c0.08,0.01,0.17,0.01,0.25,0.01c-8.4,5.73-14.54,14.99-15.99,27.02
            c-3.82,31.75,28.89,61.2,60.16,82.14c-0.15-0.05-0.29-0.11-0.44-0.16c-9.07-3.1-19.12-3.11-28.15-0.3
            c-0.16,0.03-0.31,0.06-0.48,0.1c-1.35,0.4-2.99,0.67-4.07,0.66c-4.7,0.24-7.78-0.77-11.17-3.63c-3.3-2.7-3.64-8.87-0.04-12.13
            c-4.89,1.75-7.49,9.39-3.85,15.04c1.95,3.02,4.71,4.67,7.89,5.69c-1.6,1.13-3.11,2.39-4.52,3.76c-1.25,1.21-2.37,2.5-3.4,3.83
            c-0.18-0.28-0.4-0.5-0.63-0.63c-1.97-1.02-2.79-1.27-5.98-0.58c-1.71,0.38-4.13,2.04-5.59,3.13c-1.81,1.36-6.04,1.63-6.04,1.63
            s4.13,2.33,6.63,3.46C19.38,225.25,17.2,227.79,15.9,229.46z M164.58,51.81c-0.08,0.05-0.15,0.1-0.22,0.16
            c-0.02-0.13-0.04-0.26-0.07-0.4C164.39,51.65,164.49,51.73,164.58,51.81z M82.87,96.82c-0.01-0.07,0-0.15-0.01-0.23
            c-0.07-1.17-0.22-2.23-0.4-3.21c0.11,0.23,0.21,0.46,0.32,0.68c0.9,1.76,1.83,3.4,2.8,4.93C84.69,98.23,83.79,97.5,82.87,96.82z
             M82.81,56.23c1.95-7.4,6.08-14.4,11.76-19.86c0.48,0.23,0.94,0.49,1.33,0.76c0.23,0.15,0.44,0.31,0.62,0.46
            c0.22,0.17,0.43,0.36,0.61,0.57c0.18,0.21,0.26,0.31,0.5,0.59c0.07,0.1,0.16,0.19,0.16,0.19c0.01,0.01,0.1,0.14,0.1,0.14
            c0.07,0.09,0.13,0.16,0.23,0.29c0.55,0.68,1.35,1.21,2.19,0.53c1.1-0.9,0.28-2.23-0.67-3.07c-0.24-0.21-0.48-0.49-0.85-0.72
            c-0.69-0.43-1.65-0.85-2.71-1.12c0.17-0.15,0.33-0.3,0.5-0.44c0.08,0,0.15,0,0.24,0.01c1.2,0.09,2.56,0.48,3.83,1.06
            c0.85,0.38,1.64,0.85,2.33,1.33c0.35,0.24,0.67,0.47,0.95,0.71c0.35,0.25,0.66,0.55,0.94,0.88c0.28,0.32,0.4,0.48,0.75,0.89
            c0.12,0.16,0.23,0.31,0.23,0.31c0.01,0.01,0.16,0.2,0.16,0.2c0.11,0.14,0.21,0.24,0.36,0.44c0.85,1.05,2.07,1.86,3.35,0.81
            c1.68-1.38,0.43-3.4-1.01-4.69c-0.38-0.33-0.76-0.76-1.31-1.11c-1.67-1.04-4.42-2.06-7.1-2.16c-0.74-0.04-1.46-0.01-2.14,0.07
            c0.53-0.4,1.06-0.79,1.61-1.16c0.48-0.03,0.99-0.04,1.53,0.01c1.61,0.11,3.42,0.64,5.1,1.41c1.13,0.51,2.19,1.13,3.11,1.76
            c0.46,0.31,0.88,0.63,1.27,0.94c0.46,0.34,0.87,0.73,1.25,1.18c0.38,0.43,0.53,0.63,1,1.19c0.17,0.21,0.33,0.41,0.33,0.41
            c0.01,0.01,0.21,0.28,0.21,0.28c0.14,0.2,0.27,0.32,0.47,0.59c1.12,1.39,2.76,2.47,4.46,1.07c2.24-1.83,0.57-4.54-1.36-6.25
            c-0.49-0.44-0.99-1.02-1.74-1.48c-2.13-1.33-5.56-2.6-8.99-2.84c2.07-0.17,4.4,0.02,6.65,0.54c1.71,0.36,3.35,0.92,4.8,1.52
            c0.73,0.3,1.41,0.62,2.03,0.94c0.75,0.34,1.41,0.76,2.07,1.25c0.65,0.49,0.91,0.73,1.73,1.35c0.29,0.24,0.56,0.47,0.56,0.47
            c0.02,0.02,0.37,0.32,0.37,0.32c0.24,0.23,0.46,0.37,0.82,0.66c1.95,1.61,4.52,2.62,6.47,0.2c2.55-3.17-0.53-6.41-3.69-8.22
            c-0.81-0.46-1.66-1.11-2.82-1.54c-3.47-1.28-8.9-2.06-13.88-1.23c-0.1,0.01-0.19,0.04-0.29,0.05c3.02-0.94,6.16-1.49,9.31-1.67
            c0.89,0.04,1.78,0.1,2.68,0.21c4.79,0.57,9.58,2.37,13.26,4.64c3.46,2.43,5.09,6.39,5.06,9.7c0.05,3.23-1.49,6.3-2.46,6.87
            c-1.22,0.81-2.17,0.59-2.24,0.63c-0.71-0.03-1.75,0.5-2.41,1.54c-0.65,0.97,0.2,2.66,2.14,2.82c0.16-0.06,2.39,0.37,5.09-1.57
            c2.72-2.31,3.89-5.87,3.91-10.37c-0.06-3.36-1.44-7.14-4.12-10.09c3.08,1.61,5.87,3.63,8.2,6.02c9.46,9.48,11,23.52,7.2,33.24
            c-1.14,3.21-2.78,5.89-4.66,8.08c-0.97,0.65-2.3,1.45-3.96,2.01c-2.27,0.8-5.1,1.14-7.79,0.79c-5.57-0.67-9.54-4.31-10.86-5.58
            c-0.54-0.5-1.18-1.09-1.66-2.09c-0.52-0.95-0.71-2.2-1.5-2.94c-0.72-0.72-2.45-0.68-3.73,1.35c-1.33,1.88-1.25,6.23,2,9.1
            c1.14,0.97,3.63,2.74,7.06,3.77c3.38,1.1,7.52,1.23,11.04,0.33c0.21-0.06,0.4-0.12,0.61-0.19c-1.51,0.67-2.99,1.15-4.33,1.42
            c-6.03,1.31-9.76,0.2-10.14,0.18c-3.31-0.59-6.48-0.5-7.38,1.23c-0.46,0.85,0.04,2.11,1.25,3.23
            c-13.88,2.63-22.22,12.49-25.73,17.64c-1.49-3.38-2.39-7.51-2.29-11.48c0.14-8.65,5.18-14.96,6.95-17.08
            c0.68-0.86,1.51-1.88,2.99-2.67c1.4-0.86,3.33-1.21,4.36-2.48c1-1.15,0.66-3.81-2.74-5.69c-3.15-1.94-9.94-1.57-13.9,3.6
            c-1.33,1.83-3.69,5.78-4.74,11.11C86.54,87.59,87.02,94,89,99.37c0.19,0.5,0.4,0.99,0.62,1.47c-1.56-2.35-3.06-4.97-4.41-7.91
            C80.72,82.88,78.82,69.41,82.81,56.23z M25.63,233.57c-0.02,0.13-0.04,0.26-0.07,0.4c-0.08-0.05-0.15-0.11-0.23-0.16
            C25.43,233.73,25.53,233.65,25.63,233.57z"></path>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="image" data-svg-origin="26.74020004272461 84.125" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
        <g data-svg-origin="26.74020004272461 84.125" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
        <defs>
        <path id="SVGID_1_" d="M96.14,116.12c0,0,13.45-31.29,44.58-21.93c31.14,9.37,21.26,46.59,19.75,49.38
                c-1.52,2.78-16.2,34.68-65.31,63.79c-31.9-19.49-72.15-50.38-68.1-84.05C31.11,89.64,76.47,80.13,96.14,116.12z"></path>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
        </clipPath>
        <g style="clip-path: url(#SVGID_2_); transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" data-svg-origin="26.74020004272461 84.125">

        <image class="editable" style="overflow: visible; transform: matrix3d(0.3975, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3775, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 27, 76, 0, 1); cursor: move; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-select: none; z-index: 1000;" width="350" height="347" xlink:href="fake.jpg" data-svg-origin="0 0">
            </image>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="text_1">
        <g>
        <defs>
        <rect id="SVGID_3_" x="9.96" y="21.99" width="170" height="28"></rect>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
        </clipPath>
        <g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);">
        <text class="editable" data-type="text" color-values="#FFFFFF;#9B2632;#DB2952" data-label="Text 1" text-anchor="middle" x="95" y="42.6" style="fill:#FFFFFF; font-family:'Andada-Regular'; font-size:22px;">Happy</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="text_2">
        <g>
        <defs>
        <rect id="SVGID_5_" x="9.96" y="49.99" width="170" height="28"></rect>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
        </clipPath>
        <g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_6_);">
        <text class="editable" data-type="text" color-values="#FFFFFF;#9B2632;#DB2952" data-label="Text 2" text-anchor="middle" x="95" y="70" style="fill:#FFFFFF; font-family:'Andada-Regular'; font-size:22px;">Anniversary</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="text_3">
        <g>
        <defs>
        <rect id="SVGID_7_" x="9.96" y="230.73" width="170" height="22"></rect>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_8_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_7_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
        </clipPath>
        <g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_8_);">
        <text class="editable" data-type="text" color-values="#FFFFFF;#9B2632;#DB2952" data-label="Text 3" text-anchor="middle" x="95" y="245" style="fill:#FFFFFF; font-family:'Andada-Italic'; font-size:14px;">To my sweetheart</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="text_4">
        <g>
        <defs>
        <rect id="SVGID_9_" x="9.96" y="266.61" width="170" height="18"></rect>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_10_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_9_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
        </clipPath>
        <g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_10_);">
        <text class="editable" id="productName" data-type="text" data-label="Text 4" color-values="#FFFFFF;#9B2632;#DB2952" text-anchor="middle" x="95" y="278" style="fill:#FFFFFF; font-family:'Andada-Regular'; font-size:9px;">Sauvignon Blanc</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Not supported in IE : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path.

Comment: It is the same if you remove clip paths. I guess it is because of 3D transform.